# unlisted chrome extension visibility on google search

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to publish my chrome extension as unlisted- so it won't appear on chrome extention search and only users with a link can install it. in such case, will my extension be visible on a regular google search? i would like to avoid that

Comment: Is your question related to some kind of private beta?

Comment: yeap- i just dont want it to appear on google search yet..

Comment: Maybe the option to publish `private` suits you. You can whitelist the emails you want to be able to install your crx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can't say for sure as far as inner workings of Google go.**

However, it's reasonably safe to assume that Google will not list it in its search results, as long as there are no public links to it elsewhere. Anecdotal evidence suggests it is the case.

Be aware that there is no authentication on installing an Unlisted item, as long as you have the link. If the link leaks, you can't easily revoke it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience google don't reference at all you're extension when you set it as private. Even in google search.

Comment: Yes It's what I meaned